# Yii2 - decimal less than 1 without leading 0

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

Basically in my MSSQL DB the record has column of value `0.21`, however in the view (model read from DB) it is `.21` everywhere without leading `0`. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide your Gridview code (only the part where it's visible)? I thought it should display as it is in DB.

Comment: Its not really a gridview problem, even in  xdebug error still occurs -> model attribute is .21 instead of 0.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MSSQL expert, but in this case `.21` is probably returned as a string by PDO. String `.21` will be recognized as a number, so `1 + '.21'` will return `1.21`, but when you want to just display this string, no transformation will be done. The easiest way (at least from PHP side) would be to typecast this value to float:

```
echo (float) '.21'; // 0.21
```

You can also configure [`AttributeTypecastBehavior`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-attributetypecastbehavior) to do this automatically at active record level:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'typecast' => [
            'class' => AttributeTypecastBehavior::class,
            'attributeTypes' => [
                'my_attribute' => AttributeTypecastBehavior::TYPE_FLOAT,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```